Is "God of your ancestors will increase your numbers a thousandfold" considered prophecy?
In Deut 1.11 Moses says: "יְהֹוָה אֱלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵכֶם יֹסֵף עֲלֵיכֶם כָּכֶם אֶלֶף פְּעָמִים וִיבָרֵךְ אֶתְכֶם כַּאֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר לָכֶם׃". I don't understand what it the "status" of this verse.
On the one hand, if we consider the verse a part of Moses' remembering the previous events, it is not consistent with the verse before and the verse after because those are mere recalls of Parshas Shoftim, and this verse speaks of the future.
On the other hand, IIRC, there were roughly 635K men between 20 and 60 years old excluding children, women, and the elderly, meaning that if this was a prophecy, Moses was speaking about three billion Jews in the Land of Israel, which seems far off reality.
How is this verse seen by commentators - is it a prophecy or not?

Rashi sees it as a blessing , as the end of the verse indicates.
